# Adding an alias for a web app so it works via two context roots

Tags: tomcat, redirect, html

I'm using Tomcat to host a few web apps. They are all running on their respective context roots. Let's call them:

```
A: https://example.com/A
B: https://example.com/B
```

I have nothing running at `/` (ROOT). I'd like to have app "A" be accessible from `/` but for historical reasons (existing apps that haven't been updated), I need to keep it running at `/A` as well.

What's the best way to do this? I've tried to add a symbolic link from `ROOT` to `A` in the `webapps` directory but Tomcat ends up loading the app twice. I can't just have two running instances of the same app - we need one single instance accessible from both `/A` and `/`. Also, note that we have mobile apps and custom scripts that are all using this app so a pure HTML redirect won't work.

Comment: If HTTP 302 redirect / => /A is out of the question, I'd say your best bet would be to add a reverse proxy (e.g. Nginx, Apache, Varnish) to handle the URL mappings.